# Install third-party software on iPad Simulator in Xcode?

Tags: ipad, xcode, xcode-simulator

Is it possible to install third-party software on iPad simulator in Xcode? Looking into installing adblock plus to do some testing without actually having a physical iPad. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to install third-party software on iPad simulator in Xcode?

No, it is not possible to install and run a 3rd party app on iPad Simulator, like you do on a physical iPad.

The only way you can get an app on an iPad Simulator is by having access to the app source code and by successfully building and running it using Xcode.